# Muscle contraction/extension percentage during normal ranges of motion

Tags: muscles

What is the typical percentage range/limits of extension/contraction during normal ranges of motions for muscles?  Assuming a rest length in a typical relaxed state.

I'm mostly interested in humans but I am also curious if it is typically the same range across other animals too?

Comment: can you be a little more clear - do you mean what percentage of muscle shortening occurs (i.e. with 100% defined as resting/non-stretched muscle)?

Comment: Yes so for example given a rest length at 100%, saying typically muscles extend to 110% and contract to 80%.  Specifically it's to determine a sensible default starting range for a motion simulation I am working on.